# Conecting open collector sensor to pin 12 (MISO) using mp3 shield

Tags: arduino, sensors

I'm using Arduino 1. I'm detecting movement through an open collector sensor. Also I'm using a Sparkfun mp3 shield and the library https://github.com/madsci1016/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/tree/master/SFEMP3Shield

The idea is to reproduce an audio file once movement has been detected.

I'm connecting the sensor to pin 12 as INPUT_PULLUP which as I have read corresponds to MISO. I'm able to have a loop where I'm detecting movement and reproduce the audio file once, but after a while it just stop working, it keeps detecting movement but not play the audio.

I'm not sure if I shouldn't connect the sensor to pin 12, because somekind of conflict. Or maybe I should set to LOW or HIGH some pin that I don't know.

Please help.

Comment: what sensor, specifics help. And I would really recommend using something not already used. Note my fork [mpflaga](https://github.com/mpflaga/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library) is the beta for the above, with most recent updates.

Comment: A0 - A5 along with D5 and D10 should be free and won't have conflicts, see the new example [MP3ButtonPlayer2.ino](https://github.com/mpflaga/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/blob/master/SFEMP3Shield/Examples/MP3ButtonPlayer2/MP3ButtonPlayer2.ino), as it is debounced.

Answer (score 1):

use A0 - A5 along with D5 and D10 should be free and won't have conflicts, see the new example [MP3ButtonPlayer2.ino](https://github.com/mpflaga/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/blob/master/SFEMP3Shield/Examples/MP3ButtonPlayer2/MP3ButtonPlayer2.ino), as it is debounced.

Comment: Do you think that connecting in MISO pin is introducing the conflict?

Comment: Very possible. Hard to say exactly. See http://www.billporter.info/forum/topic/can-pin-12-miso-be-used/ for more discussion.